# Add on click action for dynamically created list item and its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a tree list dynamically with JavaScript. It looks something like:

```
<ul>
  <li><img />First</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li><img />Item two</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

I added images in `<li>` that have children.

The following is my on click events:

```
$('li').on({
    click: function(e) {
      if (this === e.target) {
        $(this).children('i.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus')
        $(this).siblings('ul').toggle('medium');
      }
    },
    mouseover: function() {
      if ($(this).siblings('ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).children('i.glyphicon').addClass('bg-button');
      }
    },
    mouseout: function() {
      $(this).children('i.glyphicon').removeClass('bg-button');
    }
  });
```

The `i` are the images I'm using from bootstrap. My click action works for the text within the `<li>`, but how can I extend this functionality for my images within the `<li>`?

Comment: It should work. where is `<i>`?

Comment: Shouldn't `<li><img />First</li>` be `<li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-*"></i>First</li>`?

Comment: @Hemal `<i>` is within my `<li>` items. For example, if the `<li>` has children, then ...  `<li><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i>Some text</li>`

Comment: your markup is not valid.. `ul` can't be direct child of `ul`

Comment: Remove this if condition `if (this === e.target)`

Comment: @JohnR Awesome! This works! I realize my mistake lol. If you want, you can post an answer and i'll choose and close this thread.

Comment: @PranavCBalan The `<ul>` are nested but they will always be below a `<li>` first to represent a nested tree

Comment: Validate your html code here : https://validator.w3.org/check , `ul` can be inside the `li` not directly inside the `ul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `if` condition to `$(e.target).closest('li').is(this)`

```js
$('li:has(ul)').on({
  click: function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('li').is(this)) {
      $(this).children('i.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus')
      $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
    }
  },
  mouseover: function() {
    $(this).children('i.glyphicon').addClass('bg-button');
  },
  mouseout: function() {
    $(this).children('i.glyphicon').removeClass('bg-button');
  }
});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <img />First
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <img />Item two
        <ul>
          <li>Something</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <img />First
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <img />Item two
        <ul>
          <li>Something</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <img />First
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <img />Item two
        <ul>
          <li>Something</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your markup is having some issue, as `ul` can't be a `child` of another `ul`, you need to put it in a `li`

Comment: Awesome thanks for this solution! I have a new question though. My `<ul>` and `<li>` tree works as it is supposed to. Is having a `<ul>` a child of another `<ul>` a bad practice or something?  Here is an example of what I mean by my list items: https://jsfiddle.net/ka986g1a/

Comment: @philipyoo `ul` cannot be nested directly inside the element `ul`. Here is the correct format https://jsfiddle.net/ka986g1a/1/

Comment: @philipyoo see the spec https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/ul to see what are the allowed contents inside `ul`